# Old settings for Firefox Sync in Firefox 29

Tags: firefox, sync, firefox-sync, about-config

Is there a way to configure Firefox 29 to work with an self-hosted fsyncms-Server by editing e.g. some settings in about:config?

I can use my server by installing an older version of Firefox and configuring sync there. After sync is configured, I can upgrade to FF 29 and it works perfectly. So where are these settings saved?

Thanks in advance,
efzwo

Answer (score 0):

In about:config add `services.sync.username` string and type some value

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know how to change the **server** for Sync, not the **username**.